# Show that $X$ is compact iff $X_n$ compact for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X_n,d_n) $  a family of metric spaces and $(X=\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} X_n,\mathcal d ) $ a metric space with $\mathcal T_p$ the product topology is equal to the topology defined by the distance $d$, such that for all $x=(x_n)_n, y=(y_n)_n\in X$ we have  $d(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}d_n(x_n,y_n) $ and $d_n(x,y) \leq M$ for all $x, y\in X_n$.

Show that $X$ is compact iff $X_n$  compact for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

---

For the first implication, I have used the the fact that $X$ is compact and the projection maps are continuous. For the other one, I get stuck with it. any help is appreciated.

Comment: The topology of $X$ is same as the product toplogy and product of compact spaces is always compact by Tychonoff Theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Cantor's diagonal procedure to show that any sequence in $X$ has  a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Just a bit nitpicking: The first implication is only true if all $X_n \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Do you already know that the product topology on $X$ agrees with the metric topology induced by $d$?

Answer (score 1):

Since compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in metric spaces, we can show instead that that $X$ is sequentially compact. Let $\sigma=\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ be a sequence in $X$, where $x^{(n)}=\left\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; we want to construct a convergent subsequence of $\sigma$. To begin, $X_0$ is sequentially compact, so there is an infinite $N_0\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $\left\langle x_0^{(n)}:n\in N_0\right\rangle$ converges to some $y_0\in X_0$.

Suppose that $\ell\in\Bbb N$, and we have an infinite $N_\ell\subseteq\Bbb N$ and points $y_k\in X_k$ for $k\le\ell$ such that $\left\langle x_k^{(n)}:n\in N_k\right\rangle$ converges to $y_k$ for each $k\le\ell$. $X_{\ell+1}$ is sequentially compact, so there is an infinite $N_{\ell+1}\subseteq N_\ell$ such that $\left\langle x_{\ell+1}^{(n)}:n\in N_{\ell+1}\right\rangle$ converges to some $y_{\ell+1}\in X_{\ell+1}$. In this fashion we recursively construct infinite subsets $N_\ell$ of $\Bbb N$ and points $y_\ell\in X_\ell$ for each $\ell\in\Bbb N$ such that $N_{\ell+1}\subseteq N_\ell$ and $\left\langle x_\ell^{(n)}:n\in N_\ell\right\rangle$ converges to $y_\ell$.

Now let $n_0=\min N_0$, for each $k\in\Bbb N$ let

$$n_{k+1}=\min\{m\in N_{k+1}:m>n_k\}\,,$$

and let $N=\{n_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$. Then $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative integers, so $\sigma'=\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in N\right\rangle=\left\langle x^{(n_k)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$.

Let $\ell\in\Bbb N$ and consider the sequence $\left\langle x_\ell^{(n_k)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ in $X_\ell$. For all $k\ge\ell$ we have $n_k\in N_k\subseteq N_\ell$, and $\left\langle x_\ell^{(n)}:n\in N_\ell\right\rangle$ converges to $y_\ell$, so $\left\langle x_\ell^{(n_k)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ also converges to $y_\ell$. I’ll leave the last step to you.

- Let $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$. Use the result of the last paragraph to show that $\sigma'$ converges to $y$ in $X$ and hence that $X$ is sequentially compact (and therefore compact).

Answer (score 0):

One direction is the fact that the projections are continuous, and continuous maps preserve compactness.  The other (nontrivial) direction is the theorem of Tychonoff, which incidentally is equivalent to the axiom of choice.